# Character encoding issues in PHP XML output

Tags: php, xml, character-encoding

I am using a server-side PHP to call an API and return its content read by a client-side JS `XMLHttpRequest()`. The problem is, my PHP is returning letters like **á** as **Ã¡**. Here's the snippet of PHP that's causing this:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($meaning);
    foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node) {
        $link_text =  $node->nodeValue;
        $link_href = $node->getAttribute('href');
        if (strpos($link_href,'www.somelink.com/something/') !== false) {
            $node->setAttribute('href', 'http://localhost:8888/a-s/#/mylink/' . $link_text);
        }
    }
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Taking cue from a couple of answers on similar questions on SO, I tried using HTMLEntities like so:

`echo htmlentities($dom->saveHTML(), ENT_QUOTES, 'ISO-8859-15');`

However, this further garbled up the output. What this did was throw the entire result in a raw xml format devoid of all formatting. What earlier looked like this:

[image]

Now looks like this:

[image]

Funny thing is, when I don't use `HTMLEntities()`, only the first instance of **á** gets rendered as **Ã¡**. If you look at the first image, the second instance onward, **á** is rendered as **á** without any problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your code before outputting:

```
utf8_decode();
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: This doesn't change the output at all. The problem stands.

Comment: Nope! On your `php` page before the `echo $dom->saveHTML();` statement.

Comment: Did just that but the output still renders as **Ã¡**. Also, like I said in the question, it's only the first **á** that's getting rendered incorrectly. Any subsequent occurrence comes just fine.

Comment: Okay, finally I got it to work. I just had to add a `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-15"?>` to the top of my document. Thank you.